# How to populate Firebase storage images with recyclerview in android databinding

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-databinding, firebase-storage

I have an recyclerview with which populates the data through databinding. Previously i was populating the images with help of Picasso custom binding adapter, but now I am upgrading to firebase storage but not getting the code to populate it with the recyclerview. Kindly help.

Comment: i make video on how to get image to firebase recyleradupter https://youtu.be/BRrMUcuR_fQ

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example where we store a URL pointing to Storage, then download it using Glide into a recycler view.

```
// Chat message text can contain a download URL or text
public class ChatMessage {
    public String name;
    public String message;

    public ChatMessage() {
    }

    public ChatMessage(String name, String message) {
        this.name = name;
        this.message = message;
    }
}

// Use a custom ViewHolder populated from the chat message
public class ChatMessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private static final String TAG = "ChatMessageViewHolder";
    private final Activity activity;

    TextView name, message;
    ImageView image;

    public ChatMessageViewHolder(Activity activity, View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.activity = activity;
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        image = new ImageView(activity);
        ((ViewGroup)itemView).addView(image);

    }

    public void bind(ChatMessage chat) {
        name.setText(chat.name);
        if (chat.message.startsWith("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/") || chat.message.startsWith("content://")) {
            message.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // Use Glide (you could use Picaso) to load the image
            Glide.with(activity)
                    .load(chat.message)
                    .into(image);
        }
        else {
            message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            message.setText(chat.message);
        }
    }
}
```

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/puf/f49a1b07e92952b44f2dc36d9af04e3c) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE) detail how to do this in a full app